# How to save a Python list of strings for future use

Tags: python, numpy

I just did text pre-processing of 43K documents (stop words removal/tokenization etc). in python and the result is a list of processed text documents(strings). Now I am going for converting these processed strings to bag of words feature vectors.

I need help on two things.

1). It took 45 minutes on my system to get those 43K documents text pre-processed. I don't want to again do the same stuff if I restart my system later. How do I save those list of pre-processed strings?. Should I simply save it to a txt file or should I use pickle or json?. Which is more preferable in terms of faster reading in to memory and no issues. I want to do the same for a bag of words matrix(numpy matrix).

2). I am going to run LDA or k means clustering on these bag of words matrix later. What is the best solution to persist my model so that I don't have to re-run the model again?. Pickling?

Can someone suggest the right syntax to pickle in both these cases and reading back in if pickling is the solution?

Comment: read this and try it yourself on a small file first - https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: pickle or np.save should be helpful, never tried json...

Answer (score 6):

I use sklearn joblib , it is faster than the other answer which use cPickle and gzip(170ms vs 430ms for my test). And the code is simple and cool. :)

to use `joblib.dump` to save,
and `joblib.load` to read

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'filename.pkl') 


clf = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```

see more detail about it : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd cPickle it, the advantage being that you can store the list as an object. Hard to predict how big the file is gonna be, though.

I'd do the same with the model.

Use these functions for saving and loading:

```
import cPickle
import gzip

def load(file_name):
    # load the model
    stream = gzip.open(file_name, "rb")
    model = cPickle.load(stream)
    stream.close()
    return model


def save(file_name, model):
    # save the model
    stream = gzip.open(file_name, "wb")
    cPickle.dump(model, stream)
    stream.close()
```

And then simply just do sth. like:

```
model = [0.5, 0.1, 0.3, -0.2, 1.5]
save("/path/to/model_1", model]
model = load("/path/to/model_1")
```

I didn't know how your model was gonna look like, so I used a simple weight vector for the example. Just store any object you want.

Comment: Could you set this answer to "correct" if it was, please. Thanks :)